# Two vertical scroll bars

Tags: php, html, css

I am currently working on this website http://framec.co.uk and as you can see on the home page and on the product page here: http://www.framec.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&path=229&product_id=1696 there are two vertical scroll bars.

I don't know what triggered this but they have appeared on the homepage and product pages, but not the category page http://www.framec.co.uk/index.php?route=product/category&path=229

I know usually this is because of the overflow: auto style but I have checked this and there isn't any overflow: auto styling on the website, it has all been changed to overflow: hidden.

Does anyone know how to fix the issue of two vertical scroll bars? Thanks

Comment: You have `overflow-x:hidden` on your `body`.  You might be able to make that `overflow-y:hidden` and it will eliminate one of them.  I'm on a mac on chrome, so I don't really notice the double scroll bars

Comment: You have some iframe loaded on the page `_atssh` with `visibility: hidden`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `stylesheet.css` go to line 3 and remove `overflow-y: scroll;`.  You never need overflow on the HTML nor the body, it's taken care of automatically.

```
html {
    /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Then in your stylesheet.css, go to line 6 (or 5 if you just removed a line) and remove `overflow-x: hidden;`

```
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #2e3a47;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

That'll fix your problem.

UPDATE: You don't NEED to remove the one on the body, but it's not doing anything.  `overflow-x` is left and right, not up and down.

Comment: you're welcome, Anytime!